# Video and file list displaying unwanted attributes in Bolt cms

Tags: video, bolt-cms, filelist

I have uploaded a video and a file list in a page. But instead of the video and the file list it shows the attributes or records related to the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `record.twig` template of the default theme the fields revert to a dump of all attributes when there is an unknown field.

You will have to change the template yourself to make them return usable html.

For example if your video field is a `file` upload field called `video` you could use the following code to link to the video:

```
{% if record.video is not empty %}
<video src="{{ paths.files }}{{ record.video }}"></video>
{% elseif %}
<span>No video</span>
{% endif %}
```

You can see more about content in templates in the docs at https://docs.bolt.cm/building-templates#template-tags